# animate image back to original position with jquery

Tags: jquery, effects

I am trying to animate an image on hover and bring it back to its original position when mouse leaves, image does animate but before the mouse leaves.

**Here is my code**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.logo').animate({left: "100px"}); 
    }); 

     $('.logo').mouseout(function(){
      $('.logo').animate({right: "100px"}); 

    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `-=` to decrement a property based on it's current value. Note that you need to perform this on the `left` property, as `right` is the distance of the element from the right of the containing element and is not the correct value to be setting. Also you can make the code more succinct by using the `hover()` method. Try this:

```
$('.logo').hover(function() {
  $(this).animate({ left: "100px" }); 
}, function() {
  $(this).animate({ left: "-=100px" }); 
});
```

Also note that you can achieve what you require in CSS alone using the `:hover` pseudo selector and `transition`. Try this:

```css
.logo {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #C00;
  position: absolute;
  transition: left .25s;
  left: 0;
}
.logo:hover {
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo">I am a logo!</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, actually just started learning jquery. Just trying different things.

Answer (score 0):

The `left` keyword in your `mouseenter` event callback is not showing the direction of the movement animation, that you can reset with the same size of movement in the opposite direction, but the new value for the `left` CSS property on your element.

On `mouseout` you should reset the `left` CSS property to its original value (probably 0 in your case):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.logo').mouseenter(function(){
        $('.logo').animate({left: "100px"}); 
    }); 

    $('.logo').mouseout(function(){
      $('.logo').animate({left: "0px"}); 
    }); 
});
```

But, as Rory wrote in his answer, you can achieve this animation without using JavaScript, only with CSS.